# Is there a way to alias a single, static (public) method in C#?

Tags: c#, static-methods, using-directives

In additional to allowing importing of all *types* within a namespace, the [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) in C# allows importing of a *single type* via an alias (e.g. `using A = Something.A;`) or importing all *static methods* from a type via `using static`.  In the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-directives), I don't find any mention of importing a *single, static method*.

**Question**: Is there some other way to achieve the same thing (i.e. import a **single, static method** from an external type via a *one-line* directive/statement placed at the beginning of the source file)? If not, is there any documented reason or is there any evidence of a plan to allow it in the future?

As an example and as one possible motivation for wanting to alias a particular static method rather than using all static methods (including overloads) from a class, consider the following snippet:

```
using static System.Console; // includes System.Console.WriteLine
using static System.Diagnostics.Debug; // includes System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert (as desired) and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (not desired)

class Program {
   static void Main() {
      Assert(3 + 5 == 8);
      // the following doesn't know which WriteLine to use
      WriteLine("My test passed!"); // error CS0121: The call is ambiguous
   }
}
```

Here is the syntax I'd like (which is illegal):

```
using static System.Console;
using static Assert = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert;

class Program {
   static void Main() {
      Assert(3 + 5 == 8);
      WriteLine("My test passed!");
   }
}
```

Defining a method inside the class that calls the one I want to alias, would work, but doesn't allow me to put it at the top of the file with the other using directives:

```
class Program {
   static void Assert(bool c) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(c); }
}
```

Here are some failing attempts at putting something at the top of the file:

```
using Assert = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert; // error CS0426 (i.e. Assert is not a type)
using static Assert = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert; // error CS8085: error CS8085: A 'using static' directive cannot be used to declare an alias
var Assert = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert; // error CS0815
System.Action<bool> Assert = System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert; // error CS1618
System.Action<bool> Assert = (c) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(c); // error when using Assert: error CS1618
void Assert(bool c) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(c); } // error when using Assert: error CS8801
```

Comment: You could write your own method that wraps the one you want to alias...

Comment: @RufusL Thanks; that might be the best there is. As I understand things, the method would have to be defined inside the class whereas using directives are done outside of the class, so it isn't quite what I would hope for / expect.

Comment: Rather than a wrapper method, you could define a static delegate `static Action<bool> Assert = new Action<bool>(Debug.Assert);`. But I wouldn't recommend any `using static` statements at all, its less obvious to future maintainers what each method call will actually do and where it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

There's no compile-time aliasing of that kind, but it is a simple matter to "alias" it yourself through code.

```
class Program
{
    static void WriteLine(string message) => Console.WriteLine(message);

    static void Main()
    {
        Assert(3 + 5 == 8);
        WriteLine("My test passed!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such aliasing is not straightforward because of method overloading, for example [here a list of `Console.WriteLine` overloads.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#overloads).

How to disambiguate the aliased method from its overloads?

Comment: +1 Nice observation, but isn't that issue already being handled when I do a build "using static System.Diagnostics.Debug;"?  Your point is well-taken, though---let's say I'm happy to import all overloads, but I just want one name imported.

Comment: I've updated my description to clarify that I'm okay with overloads coming as well.